# Delete data from azure sql table through spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-sql-server

I have a table in azure sql database. I want to delete some data from it using jdbc connector in pyspark.

I have tried this

```
query=delete from table where condition

spark.read\
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", 'jdbcurl') \
    .option("database", 'db') \
    .option("user", "user") \
    .option("password", "pass") \
    .option("query",query)
```

But this does not seem to work. I cannot do .load() since delete does not return anything and it gives me an error.

I found a solution here that uses a custom defined function in scala but I want to do it in python.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of queries are not supported by Apache Spark until or unless your not using Delta.
To do so you first need to create one database connection using pyodbc.
and then try running your query like this:

```
connection.execute("delete statement")
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. If I use databricks, can I do it in spark with scala(if not python) with jdbc only?

Comment: Using spark this delete operation is not possible, the only thing you can do is write in overwrite mode which is basically dropping the table and writing the new data.  if you want to use scala/java then you need to follow the same process like creating the JDBC connection and executing your delete query on that connection.